# When "would" is used as a softer form of "will"?

Tags: grammar, will-would, would

I've been studying Michael Swan's Practical English Usage and in the topic about *would* it states that:

> Would is used as a softer, less definite form of will...

Could you help me understand this by adding examples?

Comment: One use of "would" is in remote conditionals. Compare _If you **pay** the fare I **will** take a taxi_ (open) vs _If you **paid** the fare I **would** take a taxi_ (remote). Another common use is the tentative one; compare _He'**'ll** be about sixty_ (definite) vs _He'**d** be about sixty_. (tentative/vague).

Comment: Does Mr _Swan_ not give any further explanation?  If you say to someone "Will you come here, please?" it sounds rather like a command, but if you use the conditional "Would you come here, please?" it's more like a polite request.

Comment: _Would you come here, please_ is indeed a polite request, but it's not a conditional.

Comment: I ***would*** just add that if I said I ***will*** just add this comment, this would be a somewhat more "forceful" comment. But I didn't so it won't (be! :)

Comment: @KateBunting Unfortunatelly he doesn't
"Would is used as a softer, less definite form of will (see 629), or in some cases
as the past of will."

Comment: @Rodrigo -  Imagine a scenario where you are doing some family research for a friend, and you say:  "That means James **will** be your great great grandfather" versus "That means James **would** be your your great great grandfather".  Here **would** expresses less certainty than **will**.  The difference is subtle though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I notice you use "would" in "I **would** just add that if I said...", how does "would" in your sentence?

Comment: *...if I said **I will** just add this comment, this would be a somewhat **more "forceful"** comment.*  By implication, using ***would*** is somewhat ***less "forceful"***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

- "Will you help me?"
- "Would you help me?"

Using "will," depending on the tone of voice, could imply some level of irritation at the fact the other person is not yet helping.  Using the word "would," however, because it tends to be softer, is less likely to show the same level of annoyance, i.e. the speaker's tone will tend to be softer.  It is still possible to show annoyance with either word, so this is not the full story--tones of voice in English often give more meaning to a word than its definition gives it--but it is hard to sound irritated when speaking through a smile, or through a more polite word.

In some cases, "would" is nearly *required* by the grammar, and the word "will" cannot replace it.

Consider:

- "Would you like some ice cream?"

This is a polite request, but one in which "will" just doesn't fit.  Some may say that "would" gives it a conditional sense here, but most would agree that when using the modal verbs in their past-tense forms they sound more courteous.

As with many things in English, there is a word cline that ranges from commanding to a polite and humble request.

Consider:

**Modal Verb Cline**

You **will** close the window.

You **shall** close the window.

You **must** close the window.

You **need to** close the window.

You **ought to** close the window.

You **should** close the window.

You **can** close the window.

You **may** close the window.

You **could** close the window.

You **might** close the window.

The word "would" is not in this list because it would imply either *desire* to close the window or an *unreal condition* (something that did not or has not happened).  The rest are in (approximate) descending order from strongest and most forceful to gentlest and most courteous.  One may notice that the past modal forms, i.e. "could", "should," and "might" are further down in the list from their present-tense forms.  This is an approximate ordering, and some might quibble on one or more of the specifics, e.g. the ordering of "should" and "ought to" which mean virtually the same thing.

Anytime one is requesting something, the past-modal form of the request will sound more courteous.  Using the present-tense form will tend to sound more commanding.

- Will you bring in the groceries?
- Would you bring in the groceries?

Even with the addition of "please" to both of these, the form with "would" sounds much more pleasant.  It is softer and may be perceived as more gracious or respectful.  It is even possible that "Will you bring in the groceries, please?" sounds stronger than "Would you bring in the groceries?"--even without the *please*.  The word "would" just makes the sentence less commanding and more respectful of the choice of the listener as to whether or not he or she wishes to comply.

Naturally, even "would" will not counteract a harsh tone of voice.  It takes both correct wording and correct intonation to sound pleasant.